# How to handle race condition with animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a button on click of which I fadeOut an UI element, do processing to receive some data & then re render that UI element based on the received data. The problem here is, between animation & receiving data, we can’t be sure that which part will be completed first. So, let say if fadeOut animation is completed first, I have to wait until I receive the required data or let say I receive the data first, then I have to wait till the animation is completed. 
Right now, I am handling it by calling a common function which will first check if both the conditions are satisfied, if any of them isn’t satisfied, it returns. 
My pseudocode -

```
onButtonClick() {
    doSomeServiceCall(); //The data will be received in an already registered callback which I cant change.
    startFadeOutAnimation(commonFunction) //commonFunction is invoked on completion of animation
}

callBackFunctionToRecevieDataFromService (data) {
    var receivedData = data;
    if(animationStillGoingOn) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        commonFunction();
    }
}


commonFunction() {
      if(receivedData == null || AnimationNotCompletedYet)
          return;
      performReRenderOfUIComponent; //re-rendering of ui element
}
```

This solution works but I don't like it because it's kind of hacky & is difficult to understand for someone else. To make it cleaner, I thought of using javascript promises but it doesn't look like promises will help or maybe I am not able to come up with an approach which uses promises. Can there be any cleaner approach to code this in javascript?

Comment: The pseudo-code isn't enough to actually know what can be fixed or how Promises can actually apply. As your question is now I'd close it it as being too broad.

Comment: @zer00ne , actually there is nothing to be fixed. This solution works but I am looking for cleaner approaches. I may be wrong but I think any extra information added will make the question unnecessarily long.

Comment: Your question is a guessing game not broken code (which is what SO addresses). You need to post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ with real working code.

Answer (score 0):

Promises WILL help, when managing async functions.
You have to return a promise from both functions, then execute in parallel using `Promise.all()`

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all